# After installing Excel plugin in DBeaver Community Edition and there is no option to export to Excel

Tags: excel, export, dbeaver

In DBeaver Community Edition 22.2.2 I tried to install Excel plugin:

1. **Help | Install New Software**.
2. In **Work with** field I pasted: https://dbeaver.io/update/office/latest/
3. In **Name** column I have checked the *DBeaver Office Support* and Next button.
4. Then **Finish** button.
5. Restarted DBeaver.
6. Opened new DB2 session and typed in: `SELECT 1 AS one FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;` and run a SQL.
7. Right click on the result and **Export data**. *Transfer targets* dialog opens.

Now problem appears. I expect to get "XLSX ( Excel)" option, but it is not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on Export Data (arrow)
There you will se multiple options like Excel,Web Browser, Default Command
Default Command -> Check on Excel and it will always be visible.
Worked for me